# Hide menu bar in ECSlidingViewController in an option in swift

Tags: swift, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I am using ECSlidingViewController for the menu navigation. I have a option logout on which on selection logout the user. When the user login agin the menu bar will be visible instead of hidden. Swift code to hide the menu bar on logout selection.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBAction func unwindToMenuViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,   didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 4 {
        PFUser.logOut()

        var loadLoginPage: UINavigationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginNavigationController")! as UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(loadLoginPage, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Page not found @Mayank

Comment: just do bridging in swift and use ECSliding in yout project https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.slidingViewController?.resetTopViewAnimated(true)`. Then it's just a matter of removing the pan gesture recognizer of the ECSlidingViewController from the current top view and disabling any buttons that might open the menu.

Comment: slidingViewController property is not accessible. 
Is there any import needed.
I am a newbie in swift. @FruitAddict

Comment: In your obj-c bridge you need to import `UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController.h` It's an extension to UIViewController that will search the view tree for the nearest sliding view controller. If you're using cocoapods just add `#import <ECSlidingViewController/UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController.h
>`

Comment: I am using cocoapods.
In swift do we use #import?
When i  tried as you suggested i got some error. @FruitAddict

Comment: You must've created the objective c bridge somewhere to even get ECSlidingController to work. Just import it the same way you imported the other class :)

Comment: After adding cocoapods, i have only set the user defined runtime attributes to make ECsliding work. I haven't add any objective c bridge myself. @FruitAdddict

Comment: Read up on how to create an obj-c bridge. It's recommended to do it this way and is easier to maintain.

Comment: After adding obj-c bridge now i am able to access the function, but the self.slidingViewController?.resetTopViewAnimated(true) is not working.
Showing MenuTableViewController does not have a member  named slidingViewController @FruitAddict

Comment: var slidingViewController: ECSlidingViewController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! ECSlidingViewController
            slidingViewController.resetTopViewAnimated(true)

At last worked thanks @FruitAddict

Answer (score 0):

```
var slidingViewController: ECSlidingViewController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! ECSlidingViewController  
slidingViewController.resetTopViewAnimated(true)
```